# Using animate causes some elements to act weird and messing up the logic

Tags: jquery, css

```
$("#about").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').animate({
        'left': '-10.5em'
    }, 200, 'easeInOutQuad');
    $('#underwater').css('background', 'rgb(16, 66, 89)');
    if ($('#underwater').css('opacity') == 1) {
        $("#waves_1").data('dir', true).css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px');
        $("#waves_2").data('dir', false).css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px');
        $("#underwater").css('height', win.height()).animate({
            'height': 0 + 20
        }, 300, 'easeInOutQuad')
        $("#waves_1, #waves_2").stop().animate({
            'bottom': 0
        }, 300, 'easeInOutQuad');
        $("#underwater").animate({
            'opacity': 0
        }, 100, 'easeInOutQuad');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".pg-content").hide();
        }, 1000);
        tide(); //  get the waves moving
        tide2();
        setTimeout(function () {
            q_about();
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $("#waves_1, #waves_2").stop().animate({
            'bottom': win.height()
        }, 3000, 'easeInOutQuad');
        $("#underwater").css('height', 0).css('opacity', 1).show().animate({
            'height': win.height() + 20
        }, 3000, 'easeInOutQuad')
        $("#q_about").show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            nav_out();
        }, 3100);
    }
});
```

*`.pg-content` is under #underwater*

Functions that are being called within the `#about` click

```
function q_about() {
    $("#waves_1, #waves_2").stop().animate({
        'bottom': win.height()
    }, 750, 'easeInOutQuad');
    $("#underwater").css('height', 0).css('opacity', 1).show().animate({
        'height': win.height() + 20
    }, 750, 'easeInOutQuad');
    $("#q_about").show();
    $('nav').animate({
        'left': '-4.5em'
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuad');
};
```

If you noticed above, the `nav` is being sent on the extreme left to hide from the view area and once the animation ends, the nav becomes normal to `left : -4.5em`

```
function nav_out() {
    $('nav').animate({
        'left': '-4.5em'
    }, 200, 'easeInOutQuad');
}
```

---

So the main issue is with the div id `#underwater` and here is the css of it

```
#underwater {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(22, 57, 85) url("imgs/noise.png") top center no-repeat;
    z-index: 1500;
    overflow: auto!important;
}
```

Upon click

```
element.style {
    width: 594px;
    height: 750px;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgb(16, 66, 89);
}
```

HTML for the water waves

*`#waves_1` and `#waves_2` has absolute positioning*

```
<div id="waves">
    <div id="waves_1" style="bottom: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="waves_2" style="bottom: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Purpose of all this is that I'm using it on a one page website and I show content that is being hidden under the id `#underwater` but when you click for instance the menu buttons, I have a couple of them with the same work-around. Often I see the `#waves_1` and `#waves_2` moving faster than the `#underwater`.

From my logic, `#waves_1` and `#waves_2` should move up accurately along with the `#underwater` since the `#underwater` is below `#waves_1` and `#waves_2` and the function creates an animation where the water grows height and becomes the screen size height pushing up the `#waves_1` and `#waves_2`.

I explained the scenario, any improvement is welcome along side if someone can fix the issue.

I can't do the JSfiddle version as of now since I believe the defect is in the code logic which I have above but if needed, I will create a JSfiddle

### Reference Image

[image: problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function q_about() {
    $("#waves_1, #waves_2").stop().animate({ // <--- these are being called at same time.
        'bottom': win.height()
    }, 750, 'easeInOutQuad');
    $("#underwater").css('height', 0).css('opacity', 1).show().animate({ // <--- these are being called at same time.
        'height': win.height() + 20
    }, 750, 'easeInOutQuad');
    $("#q_about").show(); // <--- these are being called at same time.
    $('nav').animate({ // <--- these are being called at same time.
        'left': '-4.5em'
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuad');
};
```

You need to look into using promises or callback functions. With jQuery's animate, it is pretty easy. If you want these animations to run one after the other, do this:

```
function q_about() {
        $("#waves_1, #waves_2").stop().animate({ // <-- this runs right away
            'bottom': win.height()
        }, 750, 'easeInOutQuad', function () {
            $("#underwater").css('height', 0).css('opacity', 1).show().animate({ // <-- this runs .75 seconds after start
                'height': win.height() + 20
            }, 750, 'easeInOutQuad', function () {
                $("#q_about").show({ // <-- this runs 1.5 seconds after start
                    'complete': function () {
                        $('nav').animate({ // <-- this runs 1.9 seconds after start (400 is default duration for `.show()`)
                            'left': '-4.5em'
                        }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuad');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

Additionally, for any button that triggers animation or an ajax request of some kind, it is good practice to disable the button right away, then re-enable it once the animation and/or request is complete.

Comment: there may be more problems in your code, but I think these adjustments would be a good start.

Comment: Your answer helped me on some extent, I started doing more research on callback and got it working much better than it was before but eventually it will take more improvements because the website is dealing with alot of jquery.